# Common column names among data sets in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 6 data sets. Their names are: e10_all, e11_all, e12_all, e13_all, e14_all, and e19_all.

All have different numbers of columns and rows, but with some common columns. I need to append the rows of these columns together. First, I want to determine the columns that are common to all of the data sets, so I know which columns to select in my SQL query.

In R, I am able to do this using:

```
# Create list of dts
list_df = list(e10_all, e11_all, e12_all, e13_all, e14_all, e19_all)

col_common = colnames(list_df[[1]])

# Write for loop
for (i in 2:length(list_df)){
  col_common = intersect(col_common, colnames(list_df[[i]]))
}

# View the common columns
col_common

# Get as a comma-separated list
cat(noquote(paste(col_common, collapse = ',')))
```

I want to do the same thing, but in Python. Does anyone happen to know a way?

Thank you

Comment: Are you working with the pandas library?

Comment: @DSM Yes, I am using Pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that different in pandas.  Making some dummy dataframes:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> e10_all = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2], "B": [2,3], "C": [2,3]})
>>> e11_all = pd.DataFrame({"B": [4,5], "C": [5,6]})
>>> e12_all = pd.DataFrame({"B": [1,2], "C": [3,4], "M": [8,9]})
```

Then your code would translate to something like

```
>>> list_df = [e10_all, e11_all, e12_all]
>>> col_common = set.intersection(*(set(df.columns) for df in list_df))
>>> col_common
{'C', 'B'}
>>> ','.join(sorted(col_common))
'B,C'
```

That second line turns each of the frames' columns into a set and then takes the intersection of all of them.  A more literal translation of your code would work too, although we tend to avoid writing loops where we can avoid it, and we tend to loop over elements directly (`for df in list_df[1:]:`) rather than going via index.  Still,

```
col_common = set(list_df[0].columns)
for i in range(1, len(list_df)):
    col_common = col_common.intersection(list_df[i].columns)
```

would get the job done.